# Router being double-NATed by ISP

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, ip, port, nat

I am trying to set up an Apache server at my house which can be accessed through port 80 by my home router. I was able to do this a few months ago, and then I took the website down. When I tried to set up port forwarding again, I noticed I could not access my server from my public IP (69.162.x.x).

Looking into my router's settings, I found that it had a completely different IP listed as its public IP (100.81.x.x). From my LAN, port forwarding worked through this address (can't be a private IP (?), my router assigns with 192.168.x.x), but did not work beyond my home network.

Upon some searching on Google, I found that the address my router "thought" it had was perhaps used in double NAT purposes at an ISP level. I recieved no response when trying to contact customer support.

Am I being double NATed by my ISP, or is it some issue I have overlooked?

Comment: You may find [this](https://amoss.me/2017/05/port-forwarding-behind-a-carrier-grade-nat/) helpful, and you may also want to ask your ISP if they offer static IPs and how much they charge for it _(likely~$10/mo)_. Another option would be a VPS and tunnelling traffic through it

Comment: @JW0914 Yep just as I expected they want 14 dollars for that. I can rent a VPS with internet 13 times faster at half the price, thanks for the tip!

Comment: "I received no response when trying to contact customer support." - time to switch to another ISP.

Comment: "I could not access my server from my public IP" - You can't _normally_ access other machines on the LAN via the external IP address of the router (and port forwarding) since most consumer-grade routers don't support "NAT-Loopback". (?) See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136720/apache-virtual-host-not-accessible-from-local-network

Comment: @MrWhite I was able to do it just fine a few months ago with a Netgear R6220...

Comment: @matharpre Thanks for clarifying, the [Netgear R6220 is listed as supporting "NAT-loopback"](https://kb.netgear.com/000049578/Which-NETGEAR-routers-support-NAT-loopback).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

My idea is that your ISP is now transitioning to IPv6,
where up to now it was using pure IPv4.

The new address `100.81.x.x` is reported by the `whois` service as:

```
#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/tou/
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/inaccuracy_reporting/
#
# Copyright 1997-2021, American Registry for Internet Numbers, Ltd.
#

NetRange:       100.64.0.0 - 100.127.255.255
CIDR:           100.64.0.0/10
NetName:        SHARED-ADDRESS-SPACE-RFCTBD-IANA-RESERVED
NetHandle:      NET-100-64-0-0-1
Parent:         NET100 (NET-100-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        IANA Special Use
OriginAS:       
Organization:   Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)
RegDate:        2012-03-13
Updated:        2016-04-11
Comment:        This block is used as Shared Address Space. Traffic from these addresses does not come from IANA. IANA has simply reserved these numbers in its database and does not use or operate them. We are not the source of activity you may see on logs or in e-mail records. Please refer to http://www.iana.org/abuse/ 
Comment:        Shared Address Space can only be used in Service Provider networks or on routing equipment that is able to do address translation across router interfaces when addresses are identical on two different interfaces. 
Comment:        This block was assigned by the IETF in the Best Current Practice document, 
Comment:        RFC 6598 which can be found at: 
Comment:        http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6598
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/100.64.0.0
```

Wikipedia describes the
[IPv4 shared address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_shared_address_space)
as:

> In order to ensure proper working of carrier-grade NAT (CGN), and, by
> doing so, alleviating the demand for the last remaining IPv4
> addresses, a /10 size IPv4 address block was assigned by Internet
> Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) to be used as shared address
> space.[1]
>
> This block of addresses is specifically meant to be used by Internet
> service providers (or ISPs) that implement carrier-grade NAT, to
> connect their customer-premises equipment (CPE) to their core routers.

**Conclusion:** You are now behind Carrier-Grade NAT.
If you wish to have a real IPv4 address, you should rent a
static one from your ISP.
Otherwise, the IPv4 that you find is only internal to the ISP.

Comment: How precisely did you conclude the ISP is transitioning to IPV6 if they are still using their `100.64.0.0/10` subnet?  There is no doubt the author is behind a CGN

Comment: Use of this shared **IPv4** address space is completely unrelated to enabling IPv6. It's actually possible there is a public IPv6 address yhat OP could use, or maybe no IPv6 at all.

Comment: That's beside the point. The principal reason for existence of Shared Address Space was/is to facilitate the transition to IPv6. No ISP that had a working IPv4 setup would invest in new hardware & infrastructure, software and employees just because it's the new mode. The main reason would be a dwindling reserve of IPv4 addresses.

Comment: It's just weird that you keep pushing your IPv6 idea here, it has _nothing_ to do with any IPv6 issue - on the contrary it indicates a company that's clinging to IPv4 as long as they possibly can. Even with their working IPv4 setup, they can't magically get a larger address space.

Comment: @pipe: You misunderstand the subject.

Comment: @harrymc What are we misunderstanding? Please give us a link to an IANA resource, IETF spec, or other authoritative source that establishes that use of the `100.81.x.x` block is in any way an indication that the ISP is "now transitioning" to IPv6 instead of just procrastinating?

Comment: @Dai: I have given enough explanations and links. If you refuse to understand for what reason an ISP would change its entire infrastructure with the accompanied risk of downtime and the problems caused to users such as the poster, you may continue to argue that it was done for another reason. And which one?

Comment: @harrymc With respect, you haven't given a [**logically sound**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) explanation for _that specific point_. The way I see it, an unscrupulous ISP would gladly risk downtime by switching to carrier-grade NAT if it means being able to kick-the-can on IPv6 transition for a few more years - and there are _lots_ of unscrupulous ISPs around.

Comment: @Dai: With returned respect, why would an ISP set up a mechanism for translating *IPv4 addresses to IPv4* if it had enough IPv4 addresses for the future? If it just wanted to add IPv6 support to the existing IPv4 lines, this is a trivial exercise for the ISP, requiring no big changes and no Carrier-Grade NAT.

Comment: @harrymc "why would an ISP set up a mechanism for translating IPv4 addresses to IPv4 if it had enough IPv4 addresses for the future?" - because it's a `1-to-many` mapping, not a `1-to-1` mapping. A single IP address in the `100.81.x.x` space can be used by potentially thousands of CPE routers (which in-turn could have dozens of machines behind them).

Comment: @Dai: ISPs were doing dynamic attribution of IPv4 addresses decades before Shared Address Space was invented. No need to redo the whole infrastructure for that. Doing whois on the old address finds CIDR `69.162.0.0/18`, giving 16382 IPv4 addresses. Does that look to you as enough for an ISP?

Comment: The ISP had implement CG-NAT, from the information given by the OP you can make absolutely no assumptions about IPv6 support

Comment: @hardillb: True, but I can extrapolate, knowing what other ISPs are doing.

Comment: I won't be answering more general comments here. If people think I'm extrapolating too far, they should give other specific reasons why an ISP would go to such an effort. I don't accept "you can't be sure" and don't think this is a valid reason for downvoting.

Comment: I think the point being made is that it shouldn't be the opening pretext of the answer, it would probably be fine to include it as part of your conclusion, with the last edit, but there just isn't the evidence to have it be the opening position.

Comment: @hardillb: I modified my opening sentence. Will everybody be happy now and leave alone this answer which is basically correct? Talk about nitpicking...

Comment: @harrymc That’s DHCP and is not really relevant to this conversation: while DHCP allows ISPs to efficiently allocate IP addresses on a `1-to-1` basis, two different customers cannot concurrently share an address. Whereas with CG-NAT they do, in fact *thousands* of users can concurrently share a double-NAT’d IP address, which is what SAS allows (hence `1-to-many`). Again, this is in no-way any sign of IPv6 being deployed.

Comment: @Dai: If you and the other downvoters think it's likely that the ISP invested in 2021 in old and low-performance technology, rather than in fast IPv6 switches, I'm not arguing any more. I give up.